# Can't transfer dynastic vassals

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I have a county with 4 vassals, two cities, a temple, and a barony. I can transfer two of the vassals, a burgher and the baron, to a count vassal, but not the other the other burgher and the priest. The only thing of note is that those two happen to be my kinsmen, and my succession is agnatic gavelkind, but they are far from inheriting any of my titles, nor are they heirs at all.

Comment: Umm... why would you want to do this? I can't see how you would benefit from giving away vassal barons.

Comment: I transfer my holding vassals to my High Priest (a duke vassal) before giving away the county to a feudal vassal/sub-vassal for tax purposes.

Comment: That still doesn't quite make sense. If you're over your demesne limit just find some unlanded person in your realm to give the intact county to. You'll get more taxes that way. Or promote the burgher to get even more taxes out of the county. Note that if you're only one, maybe two, counties over the limit, you'll probably get the most taxes by just keeping the intact county. You'll just have to deal with the -10 opinion penalty.